# Apk build has double size when building with Unity 2021.1.18f1 and build is not installable

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, parsing, build, size

I moved a project from from Unity 2019.4.9 to 2021.1.18 and when building for android (.apk) the file has a bit more than the double size in comparison to the older Unity (90mb in old, 205mb in new).

I haven't imported anything new in the project during the transition. When copying the build in a Xiaomi Mi 9T Pro and trying to install it this message appears : "There was a problem parsing the package", and the apk icon is replaced by the android symbol.

The settings include: - Min API: 21, - Max API: 30, - Scripting backend : IL2CPP, - Api compatibility : .NET 4.x, - Target Architectures : ARMv7, ARM64

I'm using custom AndroidManifest.xml, and no custom gradle file.

The project is using the following SDKs: Appodeal, GoogleMobileAds, Appsflyer, GameAnalytics, Firebase Analytics, Firebase Deep Linking, Firebase Remote Config, Facebook, UTNotifications, Google Play Games.

Answer (score 0):

First I think you can do a manual check on the apk file size.
This link to Unity documentation is very useful (https://docs.unity3d.com/2021.1/Documentation/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html)

I'll summarize the part you are interested in for checking the dimensions: Run the build, then once finished, "Go to the Console window (menu: Window> General> Console
), click the small drop-down panel in the top right, and select Open Editor Log ". At the bottom of the document that appears there are all the dimensions of the individual components of the build. cross-check with the same procedure for Unity 2019.

However, the 2021 version of Unity is not yet LTS, so it is still under heavy development. My advice is that you better do at least one step, going through Unity 2020, which is LTS. At least to check if the problem arises there too or if it is only related to the 2021 version.

In case the problem was only in Unity 2021 and you did not find an expected behavior, you can submit a bug report. They always replied to me, it can take a few weeks though. (https://support.unity.com/hc/en-us/articles/206336985-How-do-I-submit-a-bug-report-)

Comment: Thanks for you answer!I have already tested one of the 2020 LTS versions, and the results are the same.Today i'll expand the tests to more versions and post the answers.I haven't checked the editor log yet but will do.Thanks again, i'll get back later with more info.